# Combine duplicate rows into single row

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

In Excel, I need to combine duplicate rows as shown in Step 1 and combine into single row as shown in Step 2. How do I accomplish using VBA?

Please help.

```
Step:1
=======
| a | b | cat
----------------
| a | b | dog
----------------
| c | d | tiger
----------------
| e | f | lion
----------------
| c | d | deer
----------------

Step:2
=======
| a | b | cat,dog
---------------------
| c | d | tiger,deer
---------------------
| e | f | lion
---------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you want.

```
Sub Macro()
Dim lngRow As Long
For lngRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
If StrComp(Range("A" & lngRow), Range("A" & lngRow - 1), vbTextCompare) = 0 And StrComp(Range("B" & lngRow), Range("B" & lngRow - 1), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
    If Range("C" & lngRow) <> "" Then
        Range("C" & lngRow - 1) = Range("C" & lngRow - 1) & "|" & Range("C" & lngRow)
    End If
Rows(lngRow).Delete
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a PivotTable. The advantages of using such an approach over running some custom VBA that someone provides are:

- if you later update from A, B and C, you don't need to change your code,
- each item is sorted, but stays in separate cell so it can be easily accessed,
- you can reuse this approach in other scenarios.

Highlight your table and click Insert | PivotTable. When the PivotTable appears, drag all of the fields to the box "Rows".

Right-click on tag 'a' and choose Field settings | Layout & Print, then click 'Show labels in tabular form'. Click OK.

Repeat this for tag 'b'. You can also remove sub-totals by right-clicking on the sub-total and unchecking 'Subtotal xxx'.

I've included a screenshot below which should help.

[image: excel example]

Comment: Pivot table worked successfully for my real-time use.

Comment: Glad it helped, if it worked then please accept the answer on the left :)